# Knit word document from Shiny App with template.docx

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

I'm trying to knit a word document from a shiny app using a template.docx file. I get the following error message:

> pandoc.exe: template.docx: openBinaryFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)

The following 3 files were all currently located in the same directory.

app.R:

```
library(shiny)
library(rmarkdown)

ui <- fluidPage(

    titlePanel("Word template"),

    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(),

        mainPanel(
            downloadButton("download", "Download Report")
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

    output$download <- downloadHandler(
        
        filename = function() {
            "report.docx"
        },
        content = function(file) {
            
            src <- normalizePath('report.Rmd')
            
            owd <- setwd(tempdir())
            on.exit(setwd(owd))
            file.copy(src, 'report.Rmd', overwrite = TRUE)
            
            out <- render('report.Rmd',
                          envir = new.env(parent = globalenv()))
            
            file.rename(out, file)
        }
        
    )
    
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

report.Rmd:

````
---
title: "Test"
output:
  word_document:
    reference_docx: template.docx
    
---

`r getwd()`

```{r}
mtcars

```
````

template.docx is an empty "new" Word 2016 document

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the `downloadHandler()` function you need to copy **both .Rmd and .docx** files to the temporary directory

```
content = function(file) {
            
            src <- normalizePath(c('report.Rmd', 'template.docx')) # SEE HERE
            
            owd <- setwd(tempdir())
            on.exit(setwd(owd))
            file.copy(src, c('report.Rmd', 'template.docx'), overwrite = TRUE) # SEE HERE
            
            out <- render('report.Rmd',
                          envir = new.env(parent = globalenv()))
            
            file.rename(out, file)
        }
```