# Download a list of images to a single pdf from R Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I have looked at all similar problems posted to StackOverflow and none of them seem to be adaptable to solve my problem (so please don't mark as duplicate). I tried to make the reprex as concise as possible... Thanks in advance for any help.

**The Problem:**

I have a set of related images whose filepaths are in a dataframe, along with their category and type assignments (see the dput dataframe below). When the user clicks the "Generate Image" button, the images are read into a nested list structure according to their category and type, and then aggregated into a single jpeg to be viewed in the app. That part I have already accomplished (see the R Shiny server logic below). However, I would also like the user to be able to download this list of images as a single pdf, with each row/type of image on a separate page (see below for desired output). I've tried adapting other solutions I've found online, but can't seem to figure it out. Every attempt either results in a file error or a completely empty pdf.

**R Shiny UI and Server logic**

```
### Load packages.
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)
library(magick)

### Define UI.
ui <- fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(

        ### Sidebar menu with two buttons.
        sidebarPanel(fluid = FALSE, width = 2,
                     actionButton("go", "Generate Image"),
                     downloadButton("downloadImage", "Download Image")
        ),

        ### Main panel to view aggregate image.
        mainPanel(
            imageOutput("img")
        )
    )
)

### Define server logic.
server <- function(input, output, session) {

    # Dput dataframe containing URLs to public images and their category/type assignment.
    filenames <- structure(list(category = c("animal", "animal", "animal", "animal", 
    "animal", "nature", "nature", "nature", "nature", "nature"), 
        type = c("dog", "dog", "dog", "human", "human", "leaf", "leaf", 
        "flower", "flower", "flower"), img_url = c("https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/ce3/puppies-1-1308839.jpg", 
        "https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/006/young-dachshund-1362378.jpg", 
        "https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/20c/my-puppy-maggie-1362787.jpg", 
        "https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/fitness-picture-id172628456", 
        "https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/seventy-year-old-man-smiling-picture-id173612705", 
        "https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/6df/water-drop-on-leaf-1639205.jpg", 
        "https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/34c/close-up-macro-of-green-leaf-1641721.jpg", 
        "https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/0cf/tulips-1-1377350.jpg", 
        "https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/d2f/tulips-1400882.jpg", 
        "https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/3d3/droplets-1395002.jpg"
        )), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
    ))

    ### When the user clicks the "Generate Image" button, this generates a nested list of the 
    ### images, appended by type.
    img_list <- eventReactive(input$go, {
        by(filenames, filenames$category, function (cat) {
            by(cat, cat$type, function (t) {
                pull(t, img_url) %>% 
                    image_read() %>%
                    image_scale("x200") %>%
                    image_join() %>%
                    image_append()
            })
        })
    })
    
    ### Render aggregated image for viewing in the app.
    output$img <- renderImage({
        req(input$go)
        tmpfile <- image_join(img_list()) %>%
            image_append(stack = TRUE) %>%
            image_write(tempfile(fileext = '.jpg'), format = 'jpg')
        list(src = tmpfile, contentType = "image/jpeg")
    }, deleteFile = FALSE)
    
    ### Download image.
    output$downloadImage <- downloadHandler(
        filename = "images.pdf",
        contentType = "application/pdf",
        content = function(file) {
            ### Here is where I'm stuck!
            ###
            ### The list of images I want to print is stored in img_list()
            ### and rows of images are already correctly appended. I just 
            ### can't figure out how to print each level of the nested
            ### list to a separate page in the pdf.
        }
    )
    
    ### Stop 'listening' when browser window is closed.
    session$onSessionEnded(function() {
        stopApp()
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

My **desired output** looks like this, where the black lines represent a page break in the downloaded pdf:

[image]

Comment: You'll need to knit a markdown document from your shiny app, you send the images via the `params` argument in `render()`. You'll also need to copy all image files into the temporary directory. This isn't the same as your question, but it uses the same approach to this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62548502/8675075

Comment: @Paul thanks for your suggestion and the link. I'll give it a try.